# Just Checked Out a Commit in Git, I want to make this the master on my Local and Origin?

Tags: git

Some new changes on the repository ruined it and I had to use

```
git checkout 0885b6e57c76c0fe
```

Now It is working perfectly but I am in a `Detached HEAD` state

I would like to make this the `HEAD` and `master` of `Local` and `Origin` now

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

From the `master` branch, you can reset the repo back to that stage:

```
git reset --hard 0885b6e57c76c0fe
```

Then force push the changes:

```
git push origin master --force
```